# Why I can't run react-native app on windows

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, node-modules

I tried many answers on internet related to this problem. but I didnt solve this problem.

But I can run **expo** project properly.

**this is what I got**

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888  throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Praveen
> Matheesha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem isn't with react native, the problem is with how windows handle links  there is a space between Praveen and Matheesha so windows will considerate Praveen as a unique folder but there is no folder called Praveen so this is the error try to rename  your user name and delete that space hope this is your problem